# adding phone number extension to phonenumber regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is my current regex:

/\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}?\b/gm

It matches:

- 444-555-1234
- 246.555.8888
- 1235554567

What I need now is the **possibility, if available** for:

- 1234567890x1234
- 444-555-1234x1234
- 246.555.8888x1234

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, can someone explain the purposes of the `\b` and how the `[-.]` becomes optional if exists in string

Comment: Men what's up with these phone numbers today? You're like the 3rd or 4th which ask a question about regex with phone numbers!

Comment: @Rizier123 maybe its international phone number regex day

Comment: 1. Is it intended that `1234567890x1234` has 1 number less than all others? 2. Try this `\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}?(x\d{4})?` 3. Why do you use `\b` when you don't know what it does?

Comment: im using an example regex just trying to understand it

Comment: \b is a word boundry, \byou\b will match the "you" in a string, and a question mark ? means optional , it matches 0 or more time. [foo]? foo is optional , thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(?:\(\d{3}\)\s*|(?=[\d.-]{10,20})\b\d{3}[-.]?)\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}(x\d{4})?\b` regex. Your condition is expressed by `(?:x\d{4})?` = `x` and 4 digits if available. As per your comments, I am adding the alternative for three digits in parentheses at the beginning of the phone number.

Comment: Here's the one i am using: /(?=[\d-.]{10,20})\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}(x\d{4})?\b/gm . It works perfectly. I want to modify it to capture: (111) 555-5555x1234. Can you solve that for me and ill accept your answer? The issue is (111) with a space after.

Comment: This regex works ok on regexpal.com: `(?:\(\d{3}\)\s*|\d{3}[-.]?)\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}(x\d{4})?`. The main point is the alternative `(?:\(\d{3}\)\s*|\d{3}[-.]?)`. I had to remove `\b`s and the lookahead to make the regex start capturing.

Comment: Looks like this one that is closer to yours - `(?:\(\d{3}\)\s*|(?=[\d.-]{10,20})\b\d{3}[-.]?)\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}(x\d{4})?\b` -also works. I also fixed lookahead here, it contained a wrongly defined character class [\d-.]. A  hyphen here means a range of characters between a number and a period. To make it match just a digit, a hyphen and a period, the hyphen must be either escaped or placed in the beginning or end, e.g. [\d.-].